# Error while installing mysql database in linux server

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install MySQL database in linux system (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1 (Santiago))

I am following official mysql installation documentation from below link

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html#yum-repo-installing-mysql

But I am getting below error while running command

```
root@devdesk]# yum install mysql-community-server
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, product-id, refresh-packagekit, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: mysql-connectors-community. Please verify its path and try again
```

How to resolve this error..? and get mysql installed in server.

Comment: Can anyone please help..?

Comment: The error is fairly clear, your machine gets a 403 (forbidden) error when it tries to download from the repository.  Check if you need to set up some proxy settings.